# Sequelize - join with subselect (1:n - select last row from second table)

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I have two tables with 1:N relationship: `users` and `payments`.

I need to select all data from the first table and only the last row from the second table (all user with last payment) using Sequelize.js ORM.

In SQL something like:

```
SELECT  u.*, p.*
FROM users u 
    LEFT JOIN payments p
        ON u.id = p.user_ID
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT payment_ID, MAX(date) maxDate
        FROM payments
        GROUP BY user_ID
    ) b ON p.payment_ID = b.payment_ID
WHERE u.package = 1
```

I don't know how write this query in sequelize ORM. I can't use raw SQL because there is more logic behind, more joins, conditions etc, all written in ORM. This is only a minimal example.

My last try:

```
Users.findAll({
  where: {package: 1},
  include: [{
    model: Payments,
    where: {
      "payment_ID": sequelize.literal('MAX(date)')
    }}
   }]
});
```